# Upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04, OSX Mountain Lion broken

Tags: upgrade, macosx

I upgraded from 12.04 to 13.04 and now Mountain lion just doesn't boot. I had the latest refind installed but that doesn't work any more. In grub I see OSX but they don't work. I tried starting in recovery and force boot mac with the keyboard short-cuts. Nothing. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by OP in comments

> I solved it. I had to use gparted. It didn't seem to do anything at first. My partition looked correct. But after that, I could boot into OSX using the keyboard shortcuts and reinstall refind. And all is well.